# Code inside if condition not working in android

Tags: android, if-statement

Hi in the below code am selecting the mColorTemp seekbar .am checking if selecting colortemp then control should move to next activity.
But it is not working

```
mColorTemp = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.intensity1);
mScheduler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean swichAction=false;

                if(mColorTemp.isSelected()==true){
                    swichAction=true;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SchedulerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("swichAction",swichAction);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                }


      });
```

Comment: That mean _if(mColorTemp.isSelected()==true){_ condition not satisfying.

Comment: Why don't u direct use `if(mColorTemp.isSelected())`

Comment: First i was tried like that then also not working

Comment: Thats mean isSelected() returns false every time

Comment: For investigating write hardcoded true if(true) than check

Comment: yes if(true) means control was going

Comment: what you mean by using isSelected on a seekBar inside a button click ? it alywas return false

Comment: Maybe you want it to be `if (mColorTemp.getProgress() == ???)` or similar?